# How to get Owner name Instead of Owner id of record in apex?

Tags: apex, soql

I have below code

```
List<Task> taskList = [
      SELECT Subject, Description, CallDisposition, Owner.Name, ActivityDate
      FROM TASK 
      WHERE
        Status = 'Open'
   
        AND Whatid = :recordId
    ];
```

Which I am storing result in List but I'm getting ownerId instead of Name. When I run this in query of developer console I get it correctly. But this is not working in Apex.

Comment: I think this is same behavior on all other objects also. When you store the results in Lists and if you want to extract OwnerName then you can use for loop on Task and then in system.debug() you will get OwnerName.

Comment: Owner is, in many cases, polymorphic. You have to use specific syntax to handle these. Task Owner is polymorphic. See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_polymorph_keys.htm) about how to handle such fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see any issue in code. Owner in `Task` may be a User or a Queue. But every record will have a name.

```
List<Task> tasks = [
        SELECT Subject, Description, CallDisposition, Owner.Name, ActivityDate
        FROM TASK
        WHERE
                Status = 'Open'
        LIMIT 100
];

for(Task eachTask : tasks){
    System.debug(eachTask.Owner.Name);
}
```

I can see it prints the ownername without any issue.